# does we have animateStringAsState in compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

in compose we have some animateState such as animateIntAsState which we can use to make animate while changing value, but what if we want to make animate for String in Compose ???, example:
Text(text = "SOME VALUE")

Comment: You can use `AnimatedContent` as @MARSK mentioned in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72101129/9636037) which is a high-level animation API. Other options are low-level animation APIs like [animate*AsState](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/animation#animate-as-state) or [Animatable](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/animation#animatable) where you can easily add support for other data types other than the default ones by providing a `TwoWayConverter`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's `AnimatedContent`

```
var text by remember { mutableStateOf ("SOME TEXT") }

AnimatedContent(text){
 // You must use "it", not "text"
 Text(it)
}
```

Now, it will animate the value, whenever the `text` variable changes.

You could manipulate the animation type using the `spec` parameter it provides.

More on that [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/animation#animatedcontent)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `AnimatedContent`. The documentation is [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/animation#animatedcontent).

Comment: Sir, consider not posting link-only answers. Instead, these should be posted as comments.